# How can I run a .sh script on Google Cloud Shell on schedule?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a .sh script in Google Cloud Shell that automates my instance shutdown, backup, restart sequence.

How can I run a .sh script on Schedule (i.e. daily) in a simplest possible way?

I am not a professional and I've read all documentation about cron jobs, Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Tasks... but none of the examples in the documentation appear to detail a simple task that I need, and I do not have enough knowledge yet to understand these multiple services in details.... I just need a simple direction pointer to understand how to connect my Google Cloud Shell .sh script with any form of scheduler, as in:

Run a .sh script that I have in my virtual 5gb Cloud Sell Storage on schedule (daily at specific time), instead of manually opening Google Cloud Console and using a terminal to run the same script with "bash" command?

I just need to know what I need to learn/do to make this happen.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: you can also use Cloud Run to run a bash script

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-shell-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to be possible.  The Cloud Shell will turn off shortly after you close the tab. For this you'll need to use an actual VM.  You can run one for free using the e2 micro instance.
https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute

Once you got this setup you can learn crontab to run your script on a schedule.

Comment: Thank you. And I assume, there is a way to connect my Cloud Shell 5gb "bucket" to this VM, right? As in "how do I get to my existing Cloud Shell drive's contents from that VM that I will create"?

Comment: Or somehow authenticate from that VM machine to Google Cloud Shell, in order to run my scripts, if they are located on VM, right? I can setup the VM... I just don't understand yet on how to connect from the VM to google cloud. I am just starting...

Comment: To connect to the VM from Cloud Shell, you can use the gcloud sdk. To copy your file, you can use scp, like that: gcloud compute scp ..... The documentation is great on it

Comment: Thank you, all. This answers my question. The route I am looking for is: 1) Set up a VM on my Gcloud VPC 2) Install/Initialize Cloud SDK on that VM and connect to my Gcloud 3) Relocate my .sh scripts to this new VM 4) Use cron jobs on that VM to schedule my .sh scripts to run at specific times. Thank you, guys.

Comment: a GCP Compute Engine will allow you to SSH into the VM using a one click button and a  tab in the browser.